# How to $_POST Bootstrap Form Helper Datepicker?

Tags: php, html, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-form-helper

I already make the datepicker run, but when I `$_POST` the input of the datepicker I get a null value..

```
<div class="bfh-datepicker">
    <input id="datepickers" type="text" name="dateFrom" class="datepicker" >
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code of how you are trying to get the datepicker value?

Comment: Are you sure you are doing method="post" in your form?

Comment: Also, for debugging, start your debug console and check the request being sent to the server. It will show you all you need to know (method, parameters, etc.).

Comment: i use CI...and here's the code   
$from=$this->input->post('dateFrom');

Comment: and when I inspect Element the textbox of datepicker 
<input type="text" name="" class="form-control" placeholder="" readonly="">

Comment: Can you show us where/how you initiate the `datepicker`? The javascript.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() 
      {
       $('#datepickers').bfhdatepicker('toggle');
}

Comment: I cant see why when you inspect element there is no name for the datepicker...

Comment: This is where I get the code for my datepicker
http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/datepicker/#jquery-plugins

try to Inspect Element the datepicker textbox..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `name` option:

```
<div class="bfh-datepicker">
    <input id="datepickers" type="text" data-name="dateFrom"  class="datepicker" >
</div>
```

I got this from the [docs](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/datepicker/#example3):

Look at example 3. They use the options by using html5's data paradigm. e.g. `data-max="today"`

Note that `max` is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already included library, then just do what the documentation says, put:

```
<div class="bfh-datepicker" data-name="dateto" data-format="y-m-d"></div>
```

It will generate `<input>` tag for you. Don't forget about "data-name" option (in docs its called just "**name**")
otherwise $_POST will not contain your datepicker value.